# Azure msdeploy Python App Service

Tags: python, azure, msbuild, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy an Azure App Service running Flask on Python 3.4.  When I deploy from within Visual Studio (2015) via Web Deploy, everything works nicely.  But, when I attempt to deploy from my CI/CD server (TeamCity 10.0.3 on Windows Server 2012 R2) using an MSBuild step, the deployment succeeds without errors, but my app is apparently missing some crucial components and just throws HTTP errors on every request (my logging isn't able to capture the actual errors because the app is apparently totally hosed at this point).  I'm deploying numerous C# applications from this TeamCity instance using Web Deploy without fail.  My build has the following steps:

1. Command Line Runner - Copy publish profile (because msdeploy looks for it at ~/__profiles for some unknown reason and I can't find a flag or configuration setting to change):

   `mkdir __profiles 
   copy *.pubxml __profiles`
2. Command Line Runner - Create venv at top level folder:

   `c:\python34\python.exe -m venv env`
3. Command Line Runner - Install from requirements.txt:

   `env\scripts\pip install -r requirements.txt`
4. Powershell Runner - Stop Azure App Service
5. MSBuild Runner - Deploy (Build file path points to the .pyproj file):

   `/p:DeployOnBuild=true 
   /p:PublishProfile="My Publish Profile"
   /p:Configuration=Release
   /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True 
   /p:UserName=%WebDeployUserName%
   /p:Password=%WebDeployPassword%`
6. Powershell Runner - Start Azure App Service

[Related GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/2364)

Comment: You should ask your question here https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues and reference the two posts each other.

Comment: Could you post more details for helping reproduce your issue? Such as TeamCity configuration, deployment steps, etc.

Comment: I've updated the question and also added an issue to the PTVS issues log in GitHub.  Thank you both.